# Adding multiple user controls in table

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to put multiple user controls on the dashboard. But only one user control is visible.

**Dashboard.aspx:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="220px">
<tr>
<td>
<dc:MyControl ID="c1" runat="server"/>
</td>
<td>
<dc:MyControl ID="c2" runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It looked like the global object created in user control overwrites the other one.

I then changed my javascript code as:

**MyControl.ascx:**

```
//Display gauge on the page (has some html5 elements like canvas)
<div id="gauge1" class="gauge"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var <%=this.ClientID%>global = new jGauge(); // Create a new gauge.
<%=this.ClientID%>global.id = 'gauge1'; // Link the new gauge to the placeholder DIV.


// This function is called by jQuery once the page has finished loading.
$(document).ready(function () {
<%=this.ClientID%>global.init(); // Put the gauge on the page by initializing it.
});
</script>
```

But still only one user control is visible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to change the container ID (`gauge1`) so that it's unique for each control, otherwise it will get overwritten.  Something like this:

```
<div id="<%=this.ClientID%>gaugecontainer" class="gauge"></div>
```

And modify the Javascript to use the dynamic ID:

```
<%=this.ClientID%>global.id = '<%=this.ClientID%>gaugecontainer'; 
// Link the new gauge to the placeholder DIV.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Well I tried that, but still no success. I just can't figure out what's missing...

Comment: @benjamin54 I'm not sure; at this point I'd check Firebug for any Javascript errors / trace through the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <dc:MyControl ID="c1" runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <dc:MyControl ID="c2" runat="server"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```